# (Java)Why Integer.toOctalString() function sometimes work properly and sometime not? (look at my program for details)

Tags: java, function

I'm currently working on a program about adding the octal numbers, and which I need to use the **Integer.toOctalString()** funtion to change my decimal to octal like this: **Integer.toOctalString(5 + 3)**  which will return a correct answer **"10"** but for this one **Integer.toOctalString(221 + 2)** it will not return **223** but a strange **337**? How can I fix it, and here's my program.
Here is the picture for the question, it's hard to explain so here it is[image]
Thank you

```
package first_try;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int s, d, r;
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> data1 = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Integer> data3 = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Integer> data4 = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Integer> data5 = new ArrayList<>(3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        data1.add(k.nextInt());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        data2.add(k.nextInt());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        data3.add(k.nextInt());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        data4.add(k.nextInt());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        data5.add(k.nextInt());

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(5);
    result.add(Calculation(data1.get(0),data1.get(1),data1.get(2)));
    result.add(Calculation(data2.get(0),data2.get(1),data2.get(2)));
    result.add(Calculation(data3.get(0),data3.get(1),data3.get(2)));
    result.add(Calculation(data4.get(0),data4.get(1),data4.get(2)));
    result.add(Calculation(data5.get(0),data5.get(1),data5.get(2)));
    System.out.println(result);


}

public static int Calculation(int s, int d, int r)
{


    int num = r*(1+r)/2;
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>(num);
    ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num-1; i++)
    {
        output.add(Integer.toOctalString(s+d));
        s += d;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {
        number = Integer.parseInt(output.get((output.size()-1) - j));

        while (number > 0) {
            answer.add(number%10);
            number = number / 10;
        }

    }


    for(int key : answer)
        sum += key;

    return sum;

}
```

}

the test data I'm using now is

```
SAMPLE INPUT:    SAMPLE OUTPUT:
2 3 5            1. 36
221 2 4          2. 38
1 4 20           3. 230
10 10 10         4. 99
3245 5 11        5. 178
```

but the output I got is

```
36
48 
230 
115
208
```

Comment: 223 in octal is indeed 337. What's wrong?

Comment: If the inputs are meant to be in octal, you need to read them with `k.nextInt(8)`.

Comment: 221 is already octal which means 221 + 2

Comment: No, "221" is *NOT* "already octal"!  In Java code (what Abra refers to as "integer literals"); `221`: is decimal "221"; `0335`: octal, `0xdd`: hex.  If you want to input an octal (base 8) integer with Scanner, then use `scanner.nextInt(8)`, as  Kevin Anderson suggested.  Or type `0221` (decimal "145").  And *PLEASE* choose a more meaningful variable name than "k" for your Scanner object.

Answer (score 1):

[Java SE Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) contains links to all the versions of the *Java Language Specification*

Refer to the section on integer literals, for example in the [Java 8 version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

221 is a decimal integer literal while 0_221 is an octal literal. Hence your java code is interpreting 221 as a decimal and not as an octal.